# Not able to map jsonRequest attributes in ftl file

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to map below json file market and subMarket fields in FTL file but when i try below code its not mapping can some one help me please?.I am not able to map it since 2 days

### JsonRequest

```
{
  "ProcessOrderRequest": {
    "prevalidationMode": false,
    "hbomaxCart": {
      "lobType": "HBOMAX",
      "losgs": {
        "losg_hbomax_1": {
          "productCategory": "HBOMAX",
          "market":"ABC",
          "subMarket":"something"
          "lineItems": {
            "LINE_ITEM_00": {
              "productType": "PRODUCT",
              "billingCode": "BASE-DUMMY-201912",
              "quantity": 1
            },
            "LINE_ITEM_01": {
              "productType": "PRODUCT",
              "billingCode": "BOLT-UNLHBOMAX-201912",
              "quantity": 1,
              "promotionReferences": [
                "PROMO_ID_1"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### .ftl

```
<#if pojo.hbomaxCart??>
    "data": 
         {
         <#list pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs as key, value> 
           "market" = ${value.market} 
         </#list>
         },  
    </#if>
```

Comment: You didn't tell what do you mean by it's "not mapping", or what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the variable using its entire path properly.

```
<#if pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs.losg_hbomax_1.market??>
   "market": "${pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs.losg_hbomax_1.market}",
</#if>
```

Alternatively, you can assign the contents into a variable for easier access.

```
<#assign varname = pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs.losg_hbomax_1>
"market": "${varname.market}",
```

Comment: <#if pojo.hbomaxCart??>
      "data": 
           {
            <#if pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs.losg_hbomax_1.market??>
             "market": "${pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs.losg_hbomax_1.market}",
              </#if>
    },  
  </#if>

Comment: Hi @Rohit i used above code still its not mapping

Comment: losg_hbomax_1 is actually key foe the map we can not hard code it as pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs.losg_hbomax_1

Comment: @Krish If the key is dynamic, then it's like `pojo.hbomaxCart.losgs[variableThatStoresTheActualKey].market`.